# Onclick copy input text to another location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a admin panel. When users input data into a text field i want to copy the data in the text field to another text field.
My problem is the code works until i added a insert into database function to the same button. 
How do i get the button to perform both functions. is there a better way to do the onclick function. As i am using two text fields but i really want one to be the product title. Like in the image below:

[image]

Code is

```
    <?php
    $add_product_errors = array();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // price validate - must be decimal(float)
        if (empty($_POST['price']) || !filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || ($_POST['price'] <= 0)) {
            $add_product_errors['price'] = "Please enter a product price";
        }
        // item name validate
        if (empty($_POST['item_name'])) {
            $add_product_errors['item_name'] = "Please enter a name";
        }
        // item name description
        if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
            $add_product_errors['desc'] = "Please enter a product description";
        }

        //add to database
        //if (empty($add_product_errors)) {
        $q = 'INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name,Product_Desc,Product_Price)   VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);

        //debugging
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $item_name, $desc, $price);
        $item_name = strip_tags($_POST['item_name']);
        $desc = strip_tags($_POST['desc']);
        //100 - changes the way the decimal displays in database
        $price = strip_tags($_POST['price'] * 100);

        //execute the query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        printf("%d Item Added.\ ", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) === 1); {
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

HTML

```
   <form name="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="admin_p.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >
            <input type="textfield" id="title" name="title" value="">
            <input type="textfield" id="item_name" name="item_name" placeholder="item name" value="" <?php $add_product_errors ?>/><br>
            <textarea id="desc" name="desc" value="" placeholder="Item description" rows="3" maxlength="200" required ><?php $add_product_errors ?></textarea><br>
            <input type="textfield" id="price" name="price" value="" placeholder="£" maxlength="30" required <?php $add_product_errors ?>/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" value="add" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">

            <!-- copy item_name to page title -->
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    document.getElementById("title").value = document.getElementById("item_name").value;
                }     
            </script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? You say it doesn't work but what is the expected result and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @J.Bush I am expecting the data in the submit button to display in another text field and for the data inputted to also insert into the database. Both functions are working individually but not together.

Comment: Does it break completely? Or is the data inserted into the database but the text not displayed in the other field?

Comment: @J.Bush it break completely, neither of the functions now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the submit input to a regular button so that you can control the control flow entirely. It might also make the control flow clearer for you to understand.

```
<form name="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="admin_p.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="myFunction()">
... your HTML here ...
<input type="button" name="add" value="add" value="add" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    // Update your field value
    document.getElementById("title").value = document.getElementById("item_name").value;

    // Submit your form.
    document.forms["product_form"].submit();
            }     
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this. I tired this, but because i added local storage, i had to use input type=submit

Comment: @jerneva if my answer worked for you, can you please mark my answer as "the answer"?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the copying of the text on the onsubmit event like this:

```
<form name="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="admin_p.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Hi thank you. But i only wanted the item_name to duplicate on submit